# Purpose of using with for python multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have been learning the multi process module in python and I notice in the 
[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) they use with Pool ...

`with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    pool.map(function,item)`
vs.

`pool=Pool(4)
pool.map(function,item)`

But in all the examples I have been seeing, and practice I have just been using pool=Pool(#). What is the difference and purpose of the with. I know that with is [used to wrap the execution of a block with methods defined by a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) but what does it achieve for Pool. I think I am just not understanding Pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the source code of the `multiprocessing.pools.Pool` class you'll see that it has:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.terminate()
```

So it simply calls the `terminate()` method for you when the context manager ends.

The `terminate()` method stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work, while the `close()` method only prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate):

> New in version 3.3: `Pool` objects now support the context management
>   protocol – see Context Manager Types. `__enter__()` returns the pool
>   object, and `__exit__()` calls `terminate()`.

Answer (score 0):

with is used in python for context management.

When used with pool, it's the equivalent of calling pool.close() after the map or apply method. 
If not called, you'll end up with a whole lot of ghost processes on your machine.

Another example, is the usage of with while handling files, thus implicitly calling f.close()

Answer (score 0):

[It just implicitly calls the `close` method:](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Connection.recv_bytes_into)

> New in version 3.3: Connection objects now support the context management protocol – see Context Manager Types. `__enter__()` returns the connection object, and `__exit__()` calls `close()`.